# Proof about union of linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> Being V a linear space of  and that W, W′ are subspaces of V . Show that if
>   V = W ∪ W′ then V = W or V = W′.

I'm having trouble doing this proof...

I'm trying to suppose by nonsense that being V = W ∪ W′ V is neither W nor W'...

- The zero vector belongs to V
- Now I'm trying to find a way that if vectors a,b belong to V it's sum is necessary in W or W' and then V is either W or W'. But I'm finding trouble proving this... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem** : If $W$ and $W'$ are subspaces then $W \cup W'$ is a subspace iff $W \subset W'$ or $W' \subset W$.

We prove it :

If $W \subset W'$ or $W' \subset W$ then we have $W \cup W' = W'$ or $W \cup W' = W$, respectively. So $W \cup W$ is a subspace.

Assuming $W' \not\subset W$, let's show $W \subset W'$. Let $x \in W$ and $y \in W' - W$. So $x,y \in W\cup W'$. Since $W \cup W'$ is a subspace, $x + y \in W \cup W'$so $x + y\in W$ or $x+y\in W'$. If $x + y \in W$ then, as $W$ is a subspace, $y = (x + y) + (-x) \in W$ which is impossible as $y \in W'-W$. So it must be that $x + y \in W'$ in which case, as $W'$ is a subspace, $x = (x + y) + (-y) \in W'$. Finally, $W \subset W'$.

In your case $W \cup W'=V$, so $W \subset W'$ or $W' \subset W$, so $W=V$ or $W'=V$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, didn't know abou that theorem :) I just have 1 question: why do you assume that if x+y either belongs to W or W'? Is it because of the assumption that W is different of W' ?

Comment: It is just the definition of the union of sets. Let $A,B$ be to sets, $A \cup B = \begin{Bmatrix} x | x \in A or x \in B\end{Bmatrix}$.